# Cassandra Client Program not Working with NettySSLOptions

Tags: ssl, cassandra, openssl, datastax-java-driver

I referred to this link https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/manual/ssl/   to implement a simple Cassandra client using datastax driver 3.0.0 on SSL with OpenSSL options but unable to run it.

Getting generic exception as  `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException` at line

```
mySession = myCluster.connect();
```

Code snippet to setup cluster connection is below.

```
    public void connectToCluster()
    {
        String[] theCassandraHosts = {"myip"};
        myCluster =
                Cluster.builder().withSSL(getSSLOption())
                        .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(2000))
                        .addContactPoints(theCassandraHosts).withPort(10742)
                        .withCredentials("username", "password")
                        .withLoadBalancingPolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build())
                        .withSocketOptions(new SocketOptions()
                        .setConnectTimeoutMillis(800).setKeepAlive(true)).build();
        try {
        mySession = myCluster.connect();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Session Established");
    }


 private SSLOptions getSSLOption()
    {
        InputStream trustStore = null;
        try
        {
            String theTrustStorePath = "/var/opt/SecureInterface/myTrustStore.jks";
            String theTrustStorePassword = "mypassword";
            List<String> theCipherSuites = new ArrayList<String>();
            theCipherSuites.add("TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            trustStore = new FileInputStream(theTrustStorePath);
            ks.load(trustStore, theTrustStorePassword.toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(ks);
            SslContextBuilder builder =
               SslContextBuilder.forClient()
                   .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
                   .trustManager(tmf)
                   .ciphers(theCipherSuites)
                   // only if you use client authentication
                   .keyManager(new File("/var/opt/SecureInterface/keystore/Cass.crt"),
                   new File("/var/opt/SecureInterface/keystore/Cass_enc.key"));
            SSLOptions sslOptions = new NettySSLOptions(builder.build());
            return sslOptions;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                trustStore.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Cassandra server is running fine with client and server encryption options. Moreover  I am able to run my client using JdkSSLOptions but have problem with NettySSLOptions.

Has anyone implemented the  NettySSLOptions for Cassandra client application?

Comment: Did you try version 3.5.0 of the driver (check https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.5/manual/ssl/)? Do you use the SSL authentication? Or you only need to have to encrypt connection?

Comment: I am using 3.0.0 driver. I am using SSL authentication for both server and client validations.

Comment: I recommend to switch to newest version. 3.0.0 was the first release in 3.x branch... Also,  I did ask about authentication,  not validation

Comment: Thanks for recommendation Alex. Will try 3.0.5 but it uses RemoteEndpointAwareNettySSLOptions. What do you mean by SSL Authentication?

Comment: Authentication I mean that user info is taken from the certificate

Comment: @AlexOtt I have used 3.5.0 driver this time but no gain. Getting same exception.

Comment: Check that you specified correct dependency to `netty-tcnative` & maybe you need to have OpenSSL? (I haven't used unfortunately)

Comment: I am using below dependency for tcnactive in my pom                 
       <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.8.Final</version>
      <classifier>linux-x86_64</classifier>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>                                                                                                         OpenSSL is in place on cassandra servers.